# Static Library dont want use .h files want use only .a file

Tags: objective-c, c, static-libraries, header-files

I have created a static library with bulk of classes. I want use that static library in my current project. I want to avoid that bulk of .h files in my app.

Is there any way to use only .a file.

Comment: Fantastic question. You added irrelevant tags only. Fixed that. Btw, what you want to do is very bad practice and you should not even consider doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way that other user code could use your library if you don't tell it the interfaces that it may use.

If you have a bulk of interfaces that you don't want to expose to the code that uses your library, you'd just have to structure it better.

Create one single `mylib-interface.h` file that has all the interfaces that you want to export and that adds all those that you must, e.g `struct` declarations that must be visible for the wanted interfaces to work. Eliminate all these interfaces from you other .h files and include `mylib-interface.h` at the top of all of those.

Now any application that wants to use your library just has to use one file, `mylib-interface.h`.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `#include` inside a header file, that's gross.

Comment: @Eregrith Competent engineering demands #include files within header files to declare what the header file uses.

Comment: I tend to make sure I `#include` the needed header before the other one inside my sources.

Comment: @Eregrith, to my opinion this is just bad design. A header file should clearly state what dependencies it imposes and resolve these dependencies at the same time. And the use of a library should only require the user to include the header file of the library and nothing else.

Comment: I am only creating that static library and i am going to use that for my app. I have 15+ classes.